# Punctuation when writing out a numbered list with the words "one", "two", etc

Tags: punctuation, numbers, lists

I am unsure of the proper way to write out a numbered list when the individual numbers "one, two", etc. are spelled out. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

"The plan failed for three reasons: one, nobody checked beforehand to see if the zoo was open on Sundays; two, my mother forgot to put mayonnaise on my sandwich again; and three, Alec Baldwin showed up."

I'm almost certain I've committed some punctuation atrocities here. What is the proper way to write this paragraph?

Comment: Such things are a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, observe the guidance of whichever [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) best suits your field and tastes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Purdue](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/44/):

> Use semi-colons between items in a list that already involve commas.
>
> ```
> - I have lived in Chicago, Illinois; Kansas City, Missouri; and Omaha,
> Nebraska. 
> - The sweaters I bought today were purple, blue, and green;
> yellow, white, and red; and pink, black, and grey.
> ```

From the [APA Style Blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/02/lists-part-2-commas-and-semicolons.html):

> **Semicolons**
>
> This gets more complex when an item or multiple items in
>   your list already have commas. In these cases, separate the items with
>   semicolons:
>
> ```
> Each child was seated at a separate station and given the following
> plush toy or toys: an elephant, which all children saw in the previous
> experiment; a kangaroo, which only half of the children saw in the
> previous experiment; or both the elephant and the kangaroo.
> ```

From these examples, it appears that your usage of semicolons to delimit a list that includes commas is correct.

If you are specifically referring to the usage of numbers within (although your sentence looks fine regardless), see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323570/how-to-use-a-numbered-list-inside-a-sentence).

Edit: I also found an MLA resource [here](https://style.mla.org/2017/06/15/serial-commas-and-semicolons/) (look for the parts on semicolons).